# How do I properly architect my home network expansion?

Tags: networking, expansion

I have FIOS verizon on 1 router w/wifi connected to 6 wireless devices, 1 network printer & 3 wired computers.  I want to add to my network, NAS storage (cloud access), 4 FIOS TV'S, Home Theatre, thermostats, security systems, security cameras, etc in a two story house.  How would you recommend adding routers & switches & where ?

Comment: the only real outlier here is the NAS. you should DMZ it if you really want it to be externally accessible.